# WInForms C++\CLI VS2013 Чтение текста из файла и вывод его в textbox

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {   
Stream^ myStream;
    openFileDialog1->Filter = "Текстовые файлы (*.txt)|*.txt|Все файлы (*.*)|*.*";

    if (openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
    {
        label1->Text = openFileDialog1->FileName;
         if ( (myStream = openFileDialog1->OpenFile()) != nullptr )
     {
        // Insert code to read the stream here.
        myStream->Close();
           textbox1->text=Convert::ToString(myStream);

     }

    }

}
```

Добрый день,не совсем могу разобраться как считать текст из файла и
 записать его в textbox,пытался использовать пример из msdn, но,видимо,не совсем понимаю как он работает.
Хотелось бы узнать,как можно считать текст в текстбокс, из выбранного мной файла?

Comment: Поясните подробней что не понятно.

Comment: какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: ошибку не выдавал

Comment: @Cerbo, вопрошающему надо построчно расписать работу кода.

Answer (score -1):

```
textBox1->Text = System::IO::File::ReadAllText(openFileDialog1->FileName,System::Text::Encoding::Default);
```

Вот это помогло